# error :activity_main can not be resolved or not a field

Tags: android, layout

getting above error .[followed this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995402/android-activity-main-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field)

but didn't find solution.checked my resource file and all but no use suggest me sutable solution for this.here placing the activity_main.xml
and [image: problem]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is `actity_main.xml` just a typo in the question or the real name of the file?

Comment: Can you show where you are using it in Java where the error is. Also, try cleaning your project, "Project --> Clean..."

Comment: @codeMagic attached the screenshot ,Rclick and view the image

Comment: @codeMagic yes tried by clean and restarting eclipse also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
setContentView(R.id.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

[From the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29) for `setContentView()`

> Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.

If you look in `R.java` in the `gen` folder, there are different classes. `R.id` is for an `id` that you give a certain `View`. `R.layout` is for a `layout` file that you create`.`setContentView`either takes a`layout`or a`View`. Not an`id`of a`View`.

Comment: No, not by far. Not a stupid question...I have seen much worse and we all start somewhere.