# Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_main'

Tags: android, sockets, mpandroidchart

i am new in android .The error is showing on this line of code, please help me how to solve this error

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;

}
```

Thank you sir!

Comment: it should be `menu_main.xml`  whatever xml resided in res/menu subfolder

Comment: I did change , but still same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - activity\_main cannot be resolved or is not a field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995402/android-activity-main-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field)

Comment: Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(junit.framework.TestResult$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Information:BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have **activity_main.xml** menu file?

Menu file looks like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

check your import statement

import  android.R;

it should be

import  yourpackage.R;