# Google Map is not getting open in my android Application?

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I have Developed my app includes Google Map.I have included Google play service lib file Also but getting this error in log cat

```
09-30 16:08:33.175: W/System.err(12349): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
09-30 16:08:33.176: W/System.err(12349):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
09-30 16:08:33.176: W/System.err(12349):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
```

my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";     
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 

     <fragment 
       android:id="@+id/MapView" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="match_parent"          
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Mainactivity class:

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment; 

public class ShowMap extends Activity 
{ 
   GoogleMap Map; 
   @Override 
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {    
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.mapview); 
       Map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.MapView)).getMap();     
 } }
```

Comment: paste your xml and java class

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894143/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable-in-android

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/MapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class ShowMap extends Activity {


 GoogleMap Map;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
  Map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.MapView)).getMap();
 }

}

Comment: Try to post your code in Question instead comment.

Comment: Check : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    
    public class ShowMap extends Activity {
    
    
     GoogleMap Map;
    
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
    
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
      Map = ((MapFragment)       getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.MapView)).getMap();
 }

}

Comment: Hi @HareshChhelana i have done all steps mentioned in that link but getting same error

Comment: can you please say what error is possible?

Comment: Hi @prakash i tried that link also but not solved my error

Comment: update your manifest code here.have you add the google play library in project,please check it.through alt+enter,then go to Android tag.check it.

Comment: right click on your project->properties->java build path ->order and  export  select all the libraries