# Google map v2 initializing error on secondary dex mechanism android

Tags: android, google-maps, ant

I'm getting an error on initializing map, when I try to use map as a external library and tried to make secondary, the apk is created and when I tried to launch map it crashes. But when I tried the same thing without dex it works fine (stacktrace is below).

How can I resolve this issue? I'm facing 65536 limit exceed error. So, it's only way to create apk, and I'm using ant.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
10-06 22:20:24.374: E/AndroidRuntime(17015):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
10-06 22:20:24.374: E/AndroidRuntime(17015):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
10-06 22:20:24.374: E/AndroidRuntime(17015):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
10-06 22:20:24.374: E/AndroidRuntime(17015):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
```

Comment: are you using proguard

Comment: @ashoke i have been tried also with progaud, same issue occured

Comment: Hi, see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15894284/4017037

Comment: Could you provide the layout XML and the code while you initialize the map?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you use google-play-services.jar.
The jar file does not include some resources.

Link the google-play-services_lib to your project.

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894143/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable-in-android/15894284#15894284)

Comment: NO, I am using google play services library project, and still getting same error

Answer (score 1):

If you use eclipce import Google Play Services from your SDK to workspace and add as library.
If you use Android Studio add gradle to this as dependecies.
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'

Here is link for developing with Google Play Services:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

You cannot use jar file for google play services.

You can find further information about 64k Limit at Jake Wharton's blog ; http://jakewharton.com/play-services-is-a-monolith/

Also with Android 5.0 Lolipop release google release a MultiDexApplication library. You should try it. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html

Note: With API v21, this feature supported natively by Android.

Comment: @Aman did you try new MultiDexApplication library? I updated answer.