# Unfortunately the app has stopped in Google maps Example

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have seen all answers but still i get the "Unfortunately the app has stopped".
My mainactivity.java

package com.example.googlemaps;

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   static final LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(21 , 57);
   private GoogleMap googleMap;

   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      try {
         if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
         }
         googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
         Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
         position(TutorialsPoint).title("TutorialsPoint"));
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
      android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature" />


   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

   <uses-feature
      android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
      android:required="true" />

   <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

      <activity
         android:name="com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>

      </activity>

      <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="AIzaSyDKymeBXNeiFWY5jRUejv6zItpmr2MVyQ0" />

   </application>
</manifest>
```

and activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the logcat shows

```
02-21 14:33:21.263: E/Trace(1674): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-21 14:33:21.314: W/dalvikvm(1674): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1999 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
02-21 14:33:21.314: D/dalvikvm(1674): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000a
02-21 14:33:21.314: D/AndroidRuntime(1674): Shutting down VM
02-21 14:33:21.314: W/dalvikvm(1674): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2fc3288)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-21 14:33:21.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1674):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i have imported google play service and searched all answer no one clarifies me.
can anybody..? Thanks

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: A simple google on your error returns the solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15894284/783707

Comment: i have imported all those things but still get app has stopped