# Android map application reports FATAL ERROR: main

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm editing an Android application that displays the current location of the user in google maps. But when I try to call the activity through an intent it crashes and closes with an error "Unfortunately the Application has stopped". I don't know why everything seems to be perfect. But the older application works without any error only the application edited and compiled now is getting crashed. Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Here is my Button XML Code:-

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hot"
        android:onClick="MyPlace"
        android:text="MyPlace" />
```

Then my java code to call the Activity:-

```
public void MyPlace(View v){
    Intent ii= new Intent(Dashboard.this,Myplace.class);
    startActivity(ii);
}
```

Myplace.java

```
package com.example.arunj.neighbour.nearestneighbor;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.arunj.neighbour.R;
import com.example.arunj.neighbour.emergencybreakdown.DatabaseHelper;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Myplace extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
GoogleMap googleMap;
DatabaseHelper dbh;
String lat, lan;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myplace);

    dbh = new DatabaseHelper(Myplace.this);
    //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) location,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    lat=String.valueOf(latitude);
    lan=String.valueOf(longitude);
    dbh.open();
    dbh.register(lat,lan);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"latitude"+lat,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"longitude"+lan,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location Registration",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myplace, menu);
    return true;
   }
}
```

AndroidManifiest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.arunj.neighbour">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.emergencybreakdown.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.arunj.neighbour.nearestneighbor.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.arunj.neighbour.nearestneighbor.Dashboard"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.arunj.neighbour.nearestneighbor.Showmaps"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_showmaps" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.arunj.neighbour.nearestneighbor.Myplace"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_myplace" >
        </activity>

        <!--<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBMLBq4wORxPZf7y2CpOzxLJ3UpEOUbjbs" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.arunj.neighbour.nearestneighbor.Power"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_power" >
        </activity>
        <!--<activity
            android:name="com.example.arunj.neighbour.emergencybreakdown.Places"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_places" >
        </activity>-->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.arunj.neighbour.emergencybreakdown.CurrentPlace"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_current_place" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.arunj.neighbour.emergencybreakdown.Admin"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_admin" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.arunj.neighbour.emergencybreakdown.AdminDash"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_admin_dash" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Logcat Message:-

```
03-23 19:10:17.302 28073-28073/com.example.arunj.neighbour E/AndroidRuntime: 

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.arunj.neighbour, PID: 28073
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1306)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3672)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2211)
at com.example.arunj.neighbour.nearestneighbor.Myplace.onCreate(Myplace.java:36)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6583)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1114)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2531)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.arunj.neighbour-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.arunj.neighbour-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1306)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3672)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2211)
at com.example.arunj.neighbour.nearestneighbor.Myplace.onCreate(Myplace.java:36)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6583)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1114)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2531)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

And one more thing the Application was created using some older versions of Android Studio but now I'm editing it with Android Studio 3.0.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894143/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable-in-android

Comment: Clean your project and then Rebuild it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by adding these dependencies in the build.gradle file of the project.

```
dependencies {  
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'    
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'  
}
```